# Something is not right with these flags

Tags: flags

Shown below are four country flags:  Brazil, Australia, Philippines and Montenegro

There is a very small thing wrong with each of the flags. It is not the Flag dimensions or colors. Something very obvious.:) Can you point it out?

No partial answers please

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this an [FTC entry](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/fortnightly-topic-challenge-45-flags?cb=1)?

Comment: Are the differences connected in some way, or are these just 4 separate puzzles?

Comment: 4 seperate puzzles

Comment: @DrD - Can you give a hint, since it seems like none of the other answers are correct?

Comment: @marsnebulasoup Bass got them right except Montenegro. Please look closely

Answer (score 4):

### Brazil

> The E in the national motto has been made larger. Normally the E should be smaller than the other letters.

### Australia

> The smallest star has seven points when it should have five.

### Philippines

> The stars are all pointing in the same direction when they should all be pointing towards the central sun.

### Montenegro

> The tongues of the eagles are colored in (gold), when only the outline should be visible (the interior should thus be red like the background).

Comment: I think you made a typo for Australia; should be rot13: "Gur fznyyrfg fgne unf frira cbvagf jura vg fubhyq unir svir."

Comment: Indeed, I don't know what was happening when I wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

Brazil:

> the image has the wrong resolution. Also, the word "E" is enlarged.

Australia:

> the small star should have only 5 points

Philippines:

> the small stars should have a point pointing at the nearest corner of the white triangle

Montenegro:

> The crown is wrong shape.

Comment: Montenegro. One small thing wrong. Please look closely

Comment: @DrD no, there are several things wrong. But you do you.

Answer (score 1):

Your version vs the original flag

> [image]

> On the Montenegro flag, there seem to be many differences (I don't know if this is due to different types of the same flag or not)

Comment: Montenegro. One small thing wrong only. Please look closely

Comment: @DrD How about *you* look closely?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the mistakes:

> [image]

Brizal:

> the “E” is larger [image]

Australia:

> the smallest star should have five angels[image]

Philippines:

> the star should be pointing different directions[image]

Montenegro:

> the tongues should only be out lined in gold, and the crown should have different shape(as circled)[image]

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers seem to be focusing on the flags in the pictures, themselves, but the question says to look for something *obvious* that is the same  (I believe) throughout all four images.

If you place all images against a black background, you can see what's obviously wrong:

> [image: flags]

> They all have a white border that is not present in the actual countries' flags. Pretty sneaky considering they just look like margins when viewed on a white background, like a PSE question...unless they are meant to be margins and I've got this all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Brazil

> Hard to tell due to the resolution but I think there is at least one four-pointed star (fourth from left) where the original Brazilian flag has all five-pointed stars.

Australia

> is supposed to have one five-pointed star on it, while in the image above, all stars have seven points

Philippines

> The three yellow-pointed stars are supposed to be rotated slightly with respect to their positions in the image above

Montenegro

> The number of feathers extending out on either wing seems to be 11 in the picture above where it should be 13.

Answer (score -2):

In the Australian flag:

> One of the stars is actually a five-point star.

In the Brazilian flag:

> The blue ellipse is oriented wrong

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! The question said "No partial answers please", and this is a partial answer as it doesn't address all of the flags. Therefore it is invalid. I encourage you to look around for some other puzzles, or make some of your own!

Comment: (from review) ISTM the problem was with having "4 separate puzzles" posted as a single question, rather than in this specific answer.